# Changed my computer language to Russian using vistalizator and print properties window became quite weird (Unkerned)

Tags: windows-7, fonts, language

I use a Windows 7 pro and its originally using Japanese and i decided to install the Russian language pack using [vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/en/index.html) for some localization work and when i try to check some program print properties page it showed up quite weird.

My  hypothesis that i don't have the correct fonts because this is originally a Japanese OS and it lacks cyrillic fonts usually used in Russia so it defaults to use some random fonts that has Cyrillic characters in them.

My question is how do i fix this? Should i install some update on windows update?

[Russian font came out wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jvIF.png)

**EDIT**:

Things that i have done:

1. Changed the system locale to Russia (before i edited this post, it was still using Japanese).
2. Rebooted the machine.

Things that i know:

1. It somehow defaults to using MS UI Gothic for the Cyrillic characters. The Cyrillic character do showed up but it has this weird-not-kerned looks (sample is in the image file that i  linked above).
2. It affects all the printer properties/selection page in windows. (At first i think that it was some local problem (just in the app that i localize))

Comment: Windows fonts as "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Courier New" do have Cyrillic characters in them. So what I would suspect is that you have sometimes installed the not correct versions of these fonts and they have overwritten the real ones from MS.

Comment: @YisroelTech Hmm how do i test that? Tried testing it in MS Word and there's no problem with the [kerning](http://imgur.com/279S2Hm). Btw i tried looking at Control Panel -> Fonts and the [preview](http://imgur.com/a/mHswx) showed up just fine :S.

Comment: The question really is which font that program's UI uses. I'd try first to reinstall all the default Windows 7 fonts (you can copy it from a clean installation.) Also, what is your System Local set to? (See here how to get to it http://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/products/software/packaged-software/translation/atlas/faq/setting-locale.html#procedure_win7)

Comment: @YisroelTech When i post this question it's using Japanese, but i have changed it to Russia the moment i replied to your first comment. My best guess is that it defaults to [MS UI Gothic](http://imgur.com/WS375LK) for reasons unknown

Comment: Have you restarted the computer after changing the system local?

Comment: And MS UI Gothic should also support Cyrillic/Russian.

Comment: @YisroelTech i have, i even rebooted it once again before replying to this comment even and the result is still the same :(.

Comment: What's actually wrong about the display? I'm not familiar with russian enough to actually understand what it says but it does look like russian text to me. What is your "non-Unicode" language set to in your "Region and Language" Settings » Administrative? If it is still Japanese try to set it to a European language.

Comment: @Seth the text came out like its not properly kerned, there's too much spacing between the characters. For example take a look at the buttons some character are cutted-off because the text isn't properly kerned.

Comment: @Seth, he answered both already. System Locale he set to Russian, and the problem is the weird spacing between the letters (seems indeed like MS UI Gothic and not one of the normal default fonts Windows is using for UI, all of which display Russian without these spacings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hints from this post

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-change-system-default-font-in-all-parts/dfce15db-7337-420a-a42e-517521a8502e

I have probably found a possible fix for my problem, so i edited my registry and try to search which one is causing this problem. Since my problem related to a font that automatically changed to MS UI Gothic. I searched for a value in this key that contain MS UI Gothic

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

And i found that MS Shell Dlg is automatically changed by my japanese computer to MS UI Gothic. So referring to my english computer, i changed that key's value to Microsoft Sans Serif. After i rebooted the japanese computer it showed the correct, kerned text!

Of course this is probably not the correct way to fix this problem, and the value is probably wrong since i don't know what is the correct value in Russian Windows 7 but this work fine (for now) in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two things:

1. Open Fonts by clicking the **Start button**, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Appearance and Personalization**, and then clicking **Fonts**.
2. In the left pane, click **Font settings**.
3. Click **Restore default font settings**.

---

1. in **Control Panel**>**Appearance and Personalization** click on **Personalization**.
2. Click on **Window Color** in the lower part of the window. The **Window Color And Appearance** windows opens.
3. Go through all the options in the **Item** dropdown, and for each of them (which isn't grayed out the Font field) see if the font is set to **Segoe UI** size **9**. If anything isn't, change it to that.

Comment: Tried #1 and i rebooted the machine and it's still using MS UI Gothic, Tried #2 and all the font settings are still using their default value (Segoe UI) (I'm using my English(US) Win 7 as a guide) i'm starting to believe that the problem lies because i'm using Vistalizator to change the language. Probably they forgot to change a thing or two in the background and probably that thing is causing this problem.

Comment: How about reinstalling Segoe UI? Here I uploaded the original set from Windows 7, extract all the fonts and install all (click replace for each that it asks if you want to replace. Then restart) https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JhX-Xrcmipmx5o-0v

Comment: hmm i don't think my problem lies on incorrect font though*(Since i can see Segoe UI is displayed correctly for cyrillic font on my russian pc). I have checked the registry files for my win7 and found the possible culprit (see my answer below). But thanks for your help!